# if value is less than prior value in a pandas dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, diff

this is what my dataframe looks like after I extract the day from the date (see last column):

```
        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  day
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    2
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000    3
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    4
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    7
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000    8
```

For my next step, I want to append another column called "Month_End" with a true/false marker if the current day is < prior day. This step is to identify the end of the month. How to do this? Thanks much.

I've tried the following with no luck so far (I'm a noob, just started python)

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if df.day.iloc[i+1] < df.day.iloc[i]:
            print (df['day'])
```

and

```
df.assign(Month_End = df.day.diff() < 0)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Do you want to find the true month end, or just the last day of the month in your data?

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it, the last day of the month in my data

Comment: So the month end solution won't work. It incorrectly excludes certain dates in my csv file, which are the months where the last trading day does not line up with the month end... Any idea for another solution to this? I thought of doing df.day < df.day.shift() but that returns the first trading day of the month not the last

Answer (score 1):

You can directly compare the date to the `MonthEnd` and see if it's `True`.

```
from pandas import offsets
df['Month_End'] = df.Date == df.Date+offsets.MonthEnd(0)
```

---

Example:

`df`:

```
        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  day
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    2
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000    3
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    4
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    7
4 2008-01-08  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000    8
5 2008-01-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000   31
6 2008-02-28  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000   28
7 2008-02-29  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000   29
8 2009-02-28  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000   28

from pandas import offsets
df.Date == df.Date + offsets.MonthEnd(0)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: Date, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df['Month_End'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])== pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + MonthEnd(0),  True, False)
```

Output:

```
        Date       AAPL      NFLX       INTC  day  Month_End
0 2008-01-02  27.834286  3.764286  25.350000    2      False
1 2008-01-03  27.847143  3.724286  24.670000    3      False
2 2008-01-04  25.721428  3.515714  22.670000    4      False
3 2008-01-07  25.377142  3.554286  22.879999    7      False
4 2008-01-31  24.464285  3.328571  22.260000    8       True
```

Comment: This is beautiful.... coming from a C++ background I can only be mirin' at this efficient code. Crazy how powerful python and pandas is... Thanks so much Joe

Comment: @EksanaStasis You are welcome. I totally agrre, lot of build-in functions. Remember to accept the answer with the tick close to the vote when it is useful :)